# Distance Matrix API: Transit travel duration broken down in segments

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I have thousands of origins and destinations for which i can get the transit travel distance and duration using the distance matrix api. I want the total travel duration broken down to segments, for example

for going from A to B

rather than getting,

**travel time (transit) = 25 mins**

i want,

**access walk time = 5 mins | bus time = 10 mins | transfer time = 3 mins |
subway time = 5 mins | egress walk time = 2 mins | TOTAL = 25 mins**

Is it possible to get the total duration broken down in segments like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the Google directions APK instead. It will give you detailled information about the route and traffic vehicles but you'll have to send a request for each origin-destination-relation.